# Understanding the conductor ideal of a ring.

Tags: commutative-algebra

Consider the inclusion of a ring $A$ into its integral closure $B$. The conductor ideal $I$ is defined as $I:=\{a\in A~|~aB\subseteq A\}$. This is supposed to describe the locus where the normalization map $\textrm{Spec}(B)\rightarrow \textrm{Spec}(A)$ fails to be an isomorphism.

Can anyone explain to me why this is the case?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried any examples with $A$ not integrally closed, such as $A = {\mathbf Z}[3i]$ or $A = k[X^2,X^3]$?

Comment: $\TeX$ tip: one never writes `~|~`. Use `\mid` or a good ol' colon there.

Comment: $\TeX$ tip continued: for proper usage of `|`, `\mid`, `\vert` etc [see here.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/498/mid-vert-lvert-rvert)

Comment: To follow up @KCd's point, if you post an example which you've attempted to work out and indicate where you are stuck, you are much more likely to get a helpful reply.  (Plus, just as important, you're likely to figure some things out just in the process of working out and writing up your attempt at the example!)

Comment: This is Bourbaki, *Commutative Algebra*, Ch. V, §1, no. 5, Corollary 5.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Consider the extension as a short exact sequence of $A$-modules.
$$ 0 \rightarrow A\rightarrow \overline{A}\rightarrow \overline{A}/A\rightarrow 0$$
This is telling us that, to get an integrally closed ring, we must extend $A$ by $\overline{A}/A$. We can think of $\overline{A}/A$ as the obstruction to $A$ being integrally closed.

Localization commutes with taking integral closures, so for $p$ any prime ideal in $A$, $\overline{(A_p)}=\overline{A}_{\overline{A}p}$.  Since localization is flat, we see that
$$ \overline{(A_p)}/A_p = \overline{A}_{\overline{A}p}/A_p = (\overline{A}/A)_p$$
So $(\overline{A}/A)_p$ is simultaneously measuring...

- the local contribution at $p$ to the global obstruction $\overline{A}/A$, and
- the obstruction to $A_p$ being integrally closed.

In particular, $A_p$ is integrally closed (and $Spec(\overline{A}_p)\rightarrow Spec(A_p)$ is an isomorphism) at those primes where $(\overline{A}/A)_p=0$.  This is the complement of the support of $\overline{A}/A$ (thought of as a coherent sheaf, if you prefer).

An equivalent definition of the conductor $I$ is the annihilator of the $A$-module $\overline{A}/A$.  Thus, $Supp(I)=Supp(\overline{A}/A)$ is the complement of the set of primes where the normalization map is an isomorphism.

Comment: (PS: Happy Birthday!)

Comment: Thanks Greg! Nice answer. :)
Alternatively, we can do this directly and localize the conductor $I$ at a prime that doesn't contain it. Then the localized conductor is trivial and the result follows.

Comment: Though the direct computation doesn't give the same intuition that your explanation does. So thanks again!

Comment: Does the direct computation ever give the same intuition that the explanation does? ;)